# Cygwin Bash from Windows Cmd Not Running Executable

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, exe

I have a program I've compiled in cygwin, that I am trying to call from a batch file a la:

```
D:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i C:/ILS/trunk/NAVAID/test.exe
```

But I am getting the error:

```
bash: C:/ILS/trunk/NAVAID/test.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

When I file test.exe inside cygwin, I get:

```
test.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

Any ideas why it won't run?  Most of the errors I've found online are from people trying to run Linux apps, but this is something compiled (via g++) directly in cygwin (on the same machine).

On Windows 8 if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try `-c <command >`

```
D:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c C:/ILS/trunk/NAVAID/test.exe
```

This runs test.exe under a bash shell. [Details on -c option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)

> There are several single-character options that may be supplied at
>   invocation which are not available with the set builtin.
>
> -c string Read and execute commands from string after processing the options, then exit. Any remaining arguments are assigned to the
>   positional parameters, starting with $0.

`-i` starts an [interactive shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shells.html#Interactive-Shells), that is not something you want in this case.

Finally for the sake of completion - bash has `--rcfile <file path>` option to give a startup file.

Comment: -c worked, not sure what the difference was, although I did have to change the path to the path that would be used be cygin, i.e., ../../cygdrive/c ...

Comment: @ Char Mourning :  Hm. In my case windows path with forward / worked.  (Mixed mode). It may be some thing with cygwin version.