# Getting the value of a cygwin environment variable from a windows script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin

I have a Windows batch script (to be honest, it's a Groovy script). In this script I determine the root directory of a Cygwin installation. The next step is to find out the current user and home directory. In Cygwin this would be just a

```
echo $HOME
#=> /home/Christian
```

What comes pretty close to my problem is the following question: [Get results of command from Cygwin in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212267/get-results-of-command-from-cygwin-in-batch).
I would like to execute something like this:

```
"C:\cygwin[64]\bin\bash[64].exe" "echo $HOME"
```

However I receive a

```
#=> /usr/bin/bash[64]: echo $HOME: No such file or directory
```

This is because `bash` is expecting a script file and I want to execute a single command. How can this be done? Is there a possibility without putting the command in a script file?

My goal is to get the Windows path to the current users home directory so that I can iterate over this directory from a Windows script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct option to issue a single command is `-c`, and before you need to perform a login with `--login`.

```
C:\>c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -c "cygpath -w $HOME"
#=> C:\cygwin64\home\Christian
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725811/734687).